# i want to restrict the user to make only select command in mysql , no delete or update or insert

Tags: mysql, selectcommand

```
                    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(strConnection);
                    MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

                    MySqlDataReader reader;
                    command.CommandText = pQuery;
                    connection.Open();
                    reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    var dataTable = new DataTable();
                    dataTable.Load(reader);

                    connection.Close();
```

I took the query from text box , I don't want user to delete or change the data in database using text box

how to restrict the command to only select command

thank you

Comment: See about user privileges in the manual

Answer (score 1):

you can create user in your database who have only the select permission , and connect to the database using that user. 
Or you can check the user input if its contains "delete" keyword using     Contains Method

```
if( pQuery.ToUpper.Contains("DELETE") or pQuery.ToUpper.Contains("UPDATE"))
{
// do something
}
else{
                MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(strConnection);
                MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

                MySqlDataReader reader;
                command.CommandText = pQuery;
                connection.Open();
                reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                var dataTable = new DataTable();
                dataTable.Load(reader);

                connection.Close();

   }
```

Comment: but if the user is db Admin he can delete all records , what I need is restriction from c# , in order to select only ,  and any user of database can only select

Comment: I need to do this from c# not from the database

Comment: my point is you don't use the admin account in this part of the application